# Passing value to synchronize thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm new to thread, so i've been trying with this for hours (i'm using XE4),

i have a simple thread

```
type
  TSendThread = class(TThread)
  private
  public
    procedure proc(const s : string);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  procedure TSendThread.proc(const S: String);
  begin
    showmessage(s);
  end;
```

Now, in my main form, i want to call that "proc" with :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t : TSendThread;
begin
    t := TSendThread.create(true);
    t.Synchronize(nil, t.proc('foo'));
end;
```

But whenever i try t compile that i get :

> There is no overloaded version of 'Synchronize' that can be called
>   with these arguments

that does not make sense (to me) because when i remove the "S" parameter from "proc" it works fine.

Comment: As first, `Synchronize` is used to be the way to access e.g. the main thread from a worker one. Do not call `Synchronize` from within the main thread.

Comment: well that was the only way i found on sending something to thread (without using the create procedure and without the "SendMessage" thing), is there anyway to send values to a thread and use the value passed?

Comment: Well, that's a different, and quite complex topic. I'm sure if you ask a question describing which *data* you want to change in your (running ?) worker thread, someone will give you a complex answer.

Comment: Well i'm just trying to Thread the Indy IdHTTP, i wanted to send to the thread 3 parameters (URL, GET/POST, lParam). I thought i could do with just calling the Synchronize method ...

Comment: @TLama: it is perfectly safe to call `Synchronize()` in the main thread. It will simply execute the specified procedure immediately. This is useful for code that doesn't know whether it is being called in the main thread or a worker thread.

Comment: @yassine_hell: in that scenario, pass the values to the thread constructor and store them in normal class members, then access them in `Execute()` as needed. You don't need to use `Synchronize()` for that. The sole purpose of `Synchronize()` is to execute some code in the main thread. If you need to have a worker thread ask the main thread for data, you can use `Synchronize()` for that, but that kind of code is a bit different than what you have presented here. You chose a bad example to ask about.

Comment: @yassine_hell I presume like a regular procedure parm that starts the function?  If that's the case, I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Calling the constructor would reset the whole thread?

Comment: @Glenn1234 yea, i thought you could just execute a procedure in the thread like in any other unit.

Comment: @yassine_hell: calling the constructor creates a new thread instance, it does not reset an existing thread. If you want to reuse the same thread instance to download multiple files, you will have to implement a queuing system inside of the thread and have the main thread post requests to the queue, and then have the thread loop through the queue, putting itself to sleep whenever the queue is empty and waking up when the queue has requests. This is getting WAY out of scope of your original question.

Comment: Yea, i guess i did not know how to put my question ... well thank you for your help, i've got a clearer idea now.

Comment: @Remy, the warning in the `Synchronize` reference says something else. Sure it applies on certain circumstances, but I wouldn't say perfectly safe. I just don't like the concept of calling `Synchronize` from outside even if it would be absolutely safe.

Comment: @TLama: if you are referring to the "Do not call Synchronize from within the main thread. This can cause an infinite loop" warning, the only way that can happen is if the synced procedure calls `Synchronize()` to sync itself again, thus resulting in a recursive loop. But best practice is to code synched procedures to be as small and self contained as possible to avoid conflicts and performance hits. So it is very unlikely to ever encounter a synched procedure that syncs itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at the various declarations of `TThread.Synchronize()`.  You are trying to call the version that takes a `TThreadMethod` as input.  `TThreadMethod` is parameter-less:

```
TThreadMethod = procedure of object;
```

That is why passing just `t.Proc` works but passing `t.Proc('foo')` does not.

With that said, you are **completely** misusing `TThread.Synchronize()`.  You don't need to create a `TThread` object in order to use the static version of `Synchronize()`.  And if you do create a `TThread` object, make it actually do something, like this:

```
type
  TSendThread = class(TThread)
  public
    fStr: String;
    procedure DoProc;
    procedure Proc(const S: string);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  procedure TSendThread.Execute;
  begin
    Proc('foo');
  end;

  procedure TSendThread.Proc(const S: string);
  begin
    fStr := S;
    Synchronize(DoProc);
  end;

  procedure TSendThread.DoProc;
  begin
    ShowMessage(fStr);
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t : TSendThread;
begin
  t := TSendThread.Create(False);
  t.WaitFor;
  t.Free;
end;
```

However, because you are using XE4, `Synchronize()` also supports anonymous procedures as well, which would eliminate your `TSendThread` class completely in this example, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      ShowMessage('foo');
    end
  );
end;
```

**Update**: given new info about what you REALLY want to do with your thread, you need to go about it like this instead:

```
type
  TSendThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fURL, fMethod, fParam: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(aURL, aMethod, aParam: string);
  end;

constructor TSendThread.Create(aURL, aMethod, aParam: string);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  fURL := aUrl;
  fMethod := aMethod;
  fParam := aParam;
end;

procedure TSendThread.Execute;
begin
  // use fURL, fMethod, and fParam as needed...
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t : TSendThread;
begin
  t := TSendThread.Create('url', 'method', 'param');
  ...
end;
```

Or like this:

```
type
  TSendThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fURL, fMethod, fParam: string;
    procedure GetValues;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TSendThread.GetValues;
begin
  fURL := ...;
  fMethod := ...;
  fParam := ...;
end;

procedure TSendThread.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(GetValues);
  // use fURL, fMethod, and fParam as needed...
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t : TSendThread;
begin
  t := TSendThread.Create(False);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: So a thread can be used without creating it? 
and as i said in the comment above, i want to send that "foo" from the Button1Click, without using the "Create". that can be done?

Comment: No, I said `Synchronize()` can be used without creating a thread object. That is because `Synchronize()` has several overloaded versions, several of which are declared as `static`.

Answer (score 3):

Synchronize only takes a parameterless procedure, as I'm sure you've figured out.  That means you have to use properties you get from the main thread in order to do certain things with it.  For instance, my thread object is named monitor:

```
Synchronize(UpdateCaption);  // as called in the thread code.

procedure monitor.UpdateCaption;
// synchronize procedure for monitor thread - updates memo on form.
begin
  With Form1.CommandText.Lines do
    Add(TextString);
end;
```

Alternatively, you pass messages to the main thread, but this is a quick in a pinch way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to write a wrapper function which takes no arguments, and call this parameterless method in `Synchronize()`.