# Pass parameters to Synchronize procedure call

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2009, synchronize

When creating a thread object, I want to call code from the application that needs to be synchronized. The problem is that I don't know how to call `Synchronize` for an application function with parameters.

Say we have

```
procedure ThreadObject.Execute;
var
  val1,val2:integer;
  Star:string;
begin
  Synchronize(funcyfunc); //how to pass val1,val2,star here?
end;
```

where `funcyfunc` is defined as follow

```
procedure OtherClass.funcyfunc(param1,param2:integer;spok:string);
begin
   letsCallFriends(spok,param1);
   letsCallFriends(spok,param2);
end;
```

now the odd solution to this would be to say in ThreadObject private

```
private
  star:string;
  val1,val2:integer;
  procedure starVal;
```

and in the implementation we do

```
procedure ThreadObject.starVal;
begin
  funcyfunc(Star,val1,val2);
end;
```

and in the thread execute we change to

```
procedure ThreadObject.Execute;
var
  val1,val2:integer;
  Star:string;
begin
  Synchronize(starVal); //how to pass val1,val2,star here?
end;
```

but this is a hassle, as for each procedure call there must be a global variable. Is there a better way?

code:

```
unit ThreadObject;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type
  TThreadObject= class(TThread)
  private
    star:string;
    val1,val2:integer;
    procedure starVal;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;

    //assume we have a constructor that ini the star val1 val2.
  end;

implementation

{ TThreadObject }

procedure ThreadObject.Execute;
var
  val1,val2:integer;
  Star:string;
begin
  Synchronize(starVal); //how to pass val1,val2,star here?
end;

procedure ThreadObject.starVal;
begin
  funcyfunc(Star,val1,val2);
end;

end.
```

Comment: [`This way`](http://pastebin.com/WD2LYNE5).

Comment: There is an excellent blog article dealing with this http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/01/30/synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing value to synchronize thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870387/passing-value-to-synchronize-thread)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use *anonymous methods*.

As you can read in the  manual for the `TThread.Synchronize`

```
Synchronize(
  procedure
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Begin Execution');
  end);
```

In the example above the *referenced variable* `Form1` would kind of like be copied and saved until the procedure gets executed (that is called *variable capture*).

*Note: David objects to the idea of "copied variable" and he probably is right. However discussing all the corner cases and implementation details would be an overkill. His comparison to "global variable" OTOH would probably have troubles with recursive procedures, etc. All the simple to grasp analogies are very rough and tilted one way or another ISTM.*

Your anonymous procedure should use your variables `val1` and `val2` and they then should get captured too

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize

Comment: FWIW, the variable is not **copied**. It is **captured**. If you have another anon method that captures the same variable, then both anon methods refer to the **same** variable. Changes made to that var by one anon method are visible in the other anon method. In such a way is a captured variable transformed from a local to a global.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and if local procedure itself changes the values between creating two anon methods ?

Comment: All three parties, the procedure that declared the locals, and the two anon methods, refer to the same variable. In fact the variable no longer resides on the stack because of course the scope of the anon methods can outlive that of the procedure that declared the variable. The captured variable is lifted into an object that resides on the heap.

Comment: i could not find when "anonymous methods." was introduced, however, it seems from this : http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/anonymousmethods_xml.html that it was introduced from delphi 2009.

Comment: @none they did exist in 2009 - for this question that is enough. But in D2006 they did not existed yet, and as 2007 is bugfoxed 2006, so i think they did not existed in 2007 too

Comment: Yes, anonymous methods were indeed introduced in D2009.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an older version of Delphi that doesn't support anonymous methods, you make your "parameters" fields on your class. I.e.

```
procedure ThreadObject.Execute;
var
  val1,val2:integer;
  Star:string;
begin
  FVal1 := val1;
  FVal2 := val2;
  FStar := Star;
  Synchronize(funcyfunc);
end;

procedure ThreadObject.FuncyFunc;
begin
  //Do stuff with FVal1, FVal2 and FStar
end;
```

Note these are **not** global.
It is also quite safe because the point of `Synchronize` is to ensure that two threads co-ordinate with each other. So, provided you don't have *other* threads trying to access the same data, you won't have any race conditions.

Yes, it is a little "klunky", but that's the advantage of using anonymous methods in newer versions of Delphi.