# Delphi asynchronous write to TListBox

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tlistbox

I want to write from multiple threads/processes to a TListBox called 'listMessages' and I have this two procedures in order to do this :

1- With adding object :

```
procedure Log(Msg: String; Color: TColor);
begin
  listMessages.Items.AddObject(Msg, Pointer(Color));
  listMessages.ItemIndex := listMessages.Items.Count -1;
end;
```

2- With TIdCriticalSection called **protectListMessages** :

```
procedure TMainForm.safelyLogMessage(mess : String);
begin
  protectlistMessages.Enter;
  try
    listMessages.Items.Add(mess);
    listMessages.ItemIndex := listMessages.Items.Count -1;
  finally
    protectListMessages.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

Can you tell me which is best(fast + thread safe) or show me a third way to write messages to my TListBox from my threads/processes ?

Comment: Neither is good. You should always add to the list box from the main thread. So you need to use `Synchronize()` to ensure the correct thread context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of your options is any good. You need to use option 3!

The point is that all access to UI controls must execute on the main thread. Use `TThread.Synchronize` or `TThread.Queue` to marshal UI code onto the main UI thread. Once you do this, the code will not need any further serialization because the very act of getting it to run on the UI thread serializes it.

The code might look like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.Log(const Msg: string; const Color: TColor);
var
  Proc: TThreadProcedure;
begin
  Proc :=
    procedure
    begin
      ListBox1.AddItem(Msg, Pointer(Color));
      ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.Count-1;
    end;

  if GetCurrentThreadId = MainThreadID then
    Proc()
  else
    TThread.Queue(nil, Proc);
end;
```

---

In your update you state that you need to write to the list box from a different process. This cannot be achieved with any of the code in the question. You need inter-process communication (IPC) for that. Sending windows messages would be a reasonable approach to take, but there are other IPC options available. But I think that you mis-speak when you use the term process. I suspect that you don't mean process, but what you do mean, I have no idea.

Comment: Can you give me an example how my code in my threads `execute` methods should look like ?

Comment: @Roman_Bezjak There are two answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21409876/224704) that may help. The first answer is only available in Delphi versions supporting anonymous methods. The second is required if you're stuck on an older version.

Comment: But if I have a timer and its `onTimer` event doesn't have `synchronize` method what should I do ?

Comment: A timer? There are no timers in the question. Timers need to execute in the main thread anyway. Well `TTimer` does because `MakeObjectInstance` is not threadsafe. What else is important here that you are not telling us?

Comment: I just have many threads that write to this TListBox called 'listMessages' - two timers, a couple of threads I create myself ( they could be 50 or more ) and a TCPServer's `OnExecute` event that also writes to `listMessages` - basically I want (if it's possible) to have one write method that all of them can use to put information in `listMessages`.

Comment: Code that executes in the UI thread, as I hope your timer methods do, do not need to call `Synchronize` or `Queue`, although it does not hurt if they do. Code outside the UI thread needs to call `Synchronize` or `Queue`. Do you understand what to call `Synchronize` and `Queue` do yet? And which version of Delphi do you use?

Comment: I changed the content of the question - by threads/processes I mean objects of class TThread, timers and a TCPServer `OnExecute` event.

Comment: It doesn't really sound to me that you understand these issues very well yet. Could you answer the questions from my previous comment?

Comment: I use Delphi XE5. So you're saying that in my `OnTimer` and `OnExecute` events I can just type `listMessages.Items.Add('some info')` and it would be thread safe ?

Comment: That's why I'm asking for help - because I don't understand these issues very well :(

Comment: I am saying that code in the UI thread needs no synchronization, and code in other threads needs to use `Synchronize` or `Queue`. Do you know whether or not any given piece of code runs in the main UI thread?

Comment: I think most of it does - yes, but I'm not sure about the `OnExecute` event - does it run in the main UI thread ?

Comment: You really need to know that sort of information. Anyway I added some code that I hope helps.

Comment: Thanks, David. I will post another question specifying what I want to do and showing more of my code.

Comment: @Roman_Bezjak: You don't need to ask a new question. David just gave you the answer here, in your execute/ontimer events, you just call the `Log`procedure...