# Thread-safety in custom class when accessing FireMonkey component

Tags: delphi, thread-safety

I am writing a custom class that should have the ability to connect to a TMemo FireMonkey component on the form in order to log info to it. The class is defined as :

```
TBlokData = class
private
  [weak] FLogMemo: TMemo;
  procedure Log(s : string);
public
  constructor Create(ConnStr: string);
  property LogMemo : TMemo read FLogMemo write FLogMemo;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

and the implementation of the `Log` method is :

```
procedure TBlokData.Log(s : string);
begin
    if Assigned(FLogMemo) then
        FLogMemo.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Now) + ': ' + s);
end;
```

I am concerned if I create the class object in a thread and populate the `LogMemo` property with, say, the `Memo1` component on the FireMonkey form, that my class will no longer be thread-safe because I will manipulate a component on the form from a thread when calling the `Log` method.

Is this a valid concern? If so, how can I make it thread-safe while maintaining the class' usability outside a threading environment as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method `LogThreadSafe`:

```
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure 
    begin
      Log(s);
    end);
```

Comment: Doesn't Synchronize already check the thread ID? No point checking twice.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize :
"**Warning:** Do not call Synchronize from within the main thread. This can cause an infinite loop."

Comment: That documentation is wrong. `TThread.Synchronize` checks the thread ID, and if we are on the main thread, it just calls the method directly and returns. It's a little pointless to pass `TThread.CurrentThread`. Better to pass `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. You're right. Sometimes I have the feeling Embarcadero has two kinds of documentation: Wrong and missing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919183/can-i-move-delphi-tthread-synchronize-locally-to-a-vcl-form-to-be-called-from

Comment: Thanks guys! I was worried about the implication of using `TThread.Synchronize` in the main thread. I guess the EMBT developers implemented the check in Synchronize at some stage and forgot to tell everyone about it ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You are right to be concerned. Your code is not threadsafe. Use `TThread.Synchronize` or `TThread.Queue` to ensure that any manipulation of the UI control are performed on the main UI thread.

As a broad rule, any manipulation of a UI component must be performed on the UI thread.

Comment: How should I execute background tasks running outside of the UI Thread?