# Multithreading questions

Tags: multithreading, delphi

1) This probably was asked a lot before, and I have read quite a lot about `Sleep` vs `WaitForSingleObject`, but still a little bit confused. As an example I have a simple background thread which is called from data-processing thread to show some message to the user without blocking data-processing thread. Which, in terms of performance (CPU usage / CPU time) is better in this case: http://pastebin.com/VuhfZUEg or http://pastebin.com/eciK92ze
I suspect that the shorter `Sleep` time is and the more flags I have, the worse performance is. On other hand with longer `Sleep` time performance will be better but reaction delay will increase, and with a lot of threads reaction delay will eventually become noticeable for user on low-end machine. Is that correct? So what is the best way to keep the "dormant", inactive threads?

2) Is `SetEvent` blocking (`SendMessage`) or non-blocking (`PostMessage`)?

3) In `TForm.OnCreate` event I have a following code:

```
procedure TFormSubsystem.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException:=LogApplicationException;
  Application.OnActivate:=InitiateApplication;
end;

procedure TFormSubsystem.LogApplicationException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
var
  ErrorFile: TextFile;
  ErrorInfo: String;
begin
  AssignFile(ErrorFile, AppPath+'Error.log');
  if FileExists(AppPath+'Error.log') then
    Append(ErrorFile)
  else
    Rewrite(ErrorFile);

    ErrorInfo:=DateTimeToStr(Now)+' Unhandled exception';
    if Assigned(Sender) then
      ErrorInfo:=ErrorInfo+' in '+Sender.UnitName+'->'+Sender.ClassName;
    ErrorInfo:=ErrorInfo+': '+E.Message;

  try
    WriteLn(ErrorFile, ErrorInfo);
  finally
    CloseFile(ErrorFile)
  end;
end;
```

It's not the best way to log errors, but it's simple. The question is: What happens if there was an exception inside `TSomeThreadAncestor.Execute` or inside a method called via `Synchronize`?

4) What exactly is difference between `Synchronize` and `Queue`? Which one I should use when my background threads interact with GUI? I don't have race conditions and already use something like semaphores.

5) Is it safe to use such constructions?

```
procedure TShowBigDialoxBoxThread.Execute;
begin
  while ThreadNotTerminated do begin
    EventHandler.WaitFor(INFINITE);
    if not(ThreadNotTerminated) then
      Continue;
    EventHandler.ResetEvent;
    Synchronize(procedure begin
      MessageDlgBig(FMsg, FDlgType, FButtons, FHelpContext, FDefaultButton, FDlgMinWidth);
    end); // this kind of Synchronize call looks fishy
  end;
end;
```

Or should I stick with calling a class method like in examples I provided above?

Edit:
I currently use Delphi XE5.

Comment: 4) `Synchronize` is blocking, while `Queue` is non-blocking. Which one you select is up to the implementation of the thread. Use `Queue` if you can.

Comment: 2) `SetEvent` is a non-blocking api call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

Edit:
Just did a few tests - it looks like with `Queue`, I don't even need background dialog-showing thread. Thanks a lot!
Still, other question stand true, since this background thread was just a small simple example and I have a much more bigger and complicated threads in my applications.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post these questions as five *separate* posts. That's how things work here. There's no bonus for packing as much as you can into a single question. In fact, you're eligible for more points by posting them separately. Points let you participate more on the site.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I thought I could post them all together because they are all related to multithreading in general and thread blocking specifically. I will keep this in mind when I post my questions.

Comment: Found an answer for #5: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870387/passing-value-to-synchronize-thread) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409876/pass-parameters-to-synchronize-procedure-call). Now I finally understand what Anonymous Methods are. If understand correctly local variables are being captured and their lifespan is extended until anonymous method finishes execution. I wonder what would happen if anonymous method called via `Queue` that lives longer than caller method would be called multiple times before it's finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling in a thread core is a bad practice if you could wait with a blocking function. What you need to learn is that a **context change** is very expensive in terms of CPU usage. The only case you should poll, when there is no other oprtion (you can't be notified when to do the work).

---

The difference is the following:

Polling:

Your thread gives the control to the thread controller by calling 'Sleep()' which forces a **context change**. After the given period (and a bit), the thread controller will give the control back to your thread initiating another **context change**. Your thread checks if it has anything to do and if not, it calls 'Sleep()' which forces another **context change**. So your thread will surely not respond while the 'Sleep()' period is over and forces *at least* 2 other **context change**s per 'Sleep()' period.

Blocking:

Your thread gives the control to the thread controller by calling 'Sleep()' which forces a **context change**, but will not wake up until you signal it. It means only one **context change** per operation, and instant answer from the signalled thread.

---

Also: 'SetEvent()' is not blocking, but you should have asked it in a different question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
So it looks like I understood the difference between `Sleep` and `WaitForSingleObject` correctly.

_The only case you should poll, when there is no other oprtion_
For example I have a Sensor thread that reads pressure values and a thread that performs vacuuming: http://pastebin.com/5QQn0jyj so I have 2 options: either leave section wrapped around `while KeepWorking and (SensorDataThread.GetSensorByName('D1').Value>SubsystemConfig.VacuumPressure) do begin` as it is or replace it with `WaitForSingleObject` but make sensor thread broadcast messages to all other threads?

Comment: If you have a thread which can wake up others only when they have work to do, do so. (Terminology: 'SetEvent()' is not a message being broadcasted but an event being raised.) Sorry, I won't read code outside your question. Also if you find my answer useful, please upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote your post since it requires 15 reputation. By "broadcasting" I meant calling `SetEvent` inside a "Sensor" thread for all of the "Working" threads.
Actually, it looks like there is no real point in using `WaitForSingleObject` here because sensor thread updates every 300ms anyway. But I can replace `Sleep(300)` with `WaitForSingleObject(EventHanlder.Handle, 300)` so I could interrupt it anytime I guess. Thanks for the reply once again!

Comment: Setevent is of course blocking, it won't return until it fails or succeeds.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Are you trying to confuse Sonic? (S)He clearly asks if SetEvent() is blocking in the manner 'SendMessage()' is blocking which means it would not return until the called thread switches context.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz so is it blocking or not? I'm confused now. And what about 
`Synchronize(procedure begin
      MessageDlgBig(FMsg, FDlgType, FButtons, FHelpContext, FDefaultButton, FDlgMinWidth);
    end); // this kind of Synchronize call looks fishy` ? I found it on [docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) but i'm not sure that a proper way to use it in big projects.

Comment: @SonicSon'edit 'SetEvent()' will set your event and return. It will not block the execution of the thread that contains it.

Comment: @mg30rg if you are answering a different question than what is being asked, then you'd better explain it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz But I don't. I'm answering _"Is SetEvent blocking (SendMessage) or non-blocking (PostMessage)?"_

Comment: Ok. Dunno... feels weird to me.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz To me too, but I answered as far as I could understand. (It seems like an issue with the poster's general knowledge on the topic and terminology, but - since (s)he wishes to learn, I'm trying to help.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. @mg30rg understood correctly what I was asking about `SetEvent` :)